# How to embed input text boxes on top of an image in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to precisely place these input text boxes on an image in bootstrap. These input text boxes would be defined relative to the image in the background and one another. I have so far been able to add a background image for a container and place input text fields on them but the placements according to the aforementioned criteria has been an issue. Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Wiredeiki App </title>
    <meta name="description" content="Wiredwiki App">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
     <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>



<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#my-navbar">
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#check_generator').css({'background-image': 'yellow'}); 
    });
</script>

  <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Wiredwiki</a>
            </div><!-- Navbar Header-->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">

            <a href="" class="btn btn-warning navbar-btn navbar-right">Download Now</a>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#feedback">Feedback</a> 
                    <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a> 
                    <li><a href="#features">Features</a> 
                    <li><a href="#faq">Faq</a> 
                    <li><a href="#contact">ContactUs</a> 
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div><!-- End Container-->
    </nav><!-- End navbar -->

    <!-- jumbotron-->

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <h1>Print Online Checks for Free</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse consectetur </p>

            <div class="btn-group">
                <a href="" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Download App</a>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Spread the word</a>
            </div>
        </div><!-- End container -->
    </div><!-- End jumbotron-->

<!-- call to action -->

<!-- Gallery -->
    <div class="container">
        <section>
            <div class="page-header" id="gallery">
                <h2>Gallery.<small> Check out the Awesome Gallery</small></h2>
            </div>

            <div class="carousel slide" id="screenshot-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="highway.jpg" alt="Text of the image">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>Highway heading</h3>
                            <p>This is the caption</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="river.jpg" alt="Text of the image">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>River heading</h3>
                            <p>This is the caption</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="street.jpg" alt="Text of the image">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>Street heading</h3>
                            <p>This is the caption</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="painting.jpg" alt="Text of the image">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>Painting heading</h3>
                            <p>This is the caption</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div><!-- End Carousel inner -->
                <a href="#screenshot-carousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                </a>
                <a href="#screenshot-carousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                </a>
            </div><!-- End Carousel -->

        </section>
    </div>

<!-- features -->
    <div class="container" id = "check_generator" onload="colorize()">
        <input type="text" id="usr">
    </div><!-- End Container -->

<!-- features -->
    <div class="container">
        <section>
            <div class="page-header" id="features">
                <h2>Features.<small> Some of the coolest Features of this app.</small></h2>
            </div><!-- End Page Header -->

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <h3>This is the heading</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam mauris tortor, eleifend sit amet fringilla ac, tincidunt id massa. Proin et odio mattis, venenatis lacus vel, faucibus elit</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="imac.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image">
                </div>
            </div><!-- End row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <h3>This is the heading</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam mauris tortor, eleifend sit amet fringilla ac, tincidunt id massa. Proin et odio mattis, venenatis lacus vel, faucibus elit</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="smartphone.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <h3>This is the heading</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam mauris tortor, eleifend sit amet fringilla ac, tincidunt id massa. Proin et odio mattis, venenatis lacus vel, faucibus elit</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="user.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image">
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                            <h4>This is the Heading</h4>
                            <p>Nam velit est, tempor vel posuere et, auctor a lectus. Aenean gravida, est accumsan dictum rhoncus, lectus mi suscipit lacus, suscipit accumsan augue tellus vitae dolor. Morbi in euismod dui</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                            <h4>This is the Heading</h4>
                            <p>Nam velit est, tempor vel posuere et, auctor a lectus. Aenean gravida, est accumsan dictum rhoncus, lectus mi suscipit lacus, suscipit accumsan augue tellus vitae dolor. Morbi in euismod dui</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
                            <h4>This is the Heading</h4>
                            <p>Nam velit est, tempor vel posuere et, auctor a lectus. Aenean gravida, est accumsan dictum rhoncus, lectus mi suscipit lacus, suscipit accumsan augue tellus vitae dolor. Morbi in euismod dui</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end row -->

        </section>
    </div><!-- End Container -->

<!-- Faq -->

    <div class="container">
      <section>
        <div class="page-header" id="faq">
          <h2>FAQ.<small> Engaging with consumers.</small></h2>
        </div><!-- End Page Header -->

        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <div class="panel-title">
                <a href="#collapse-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                  Question one?
                </a>
              </div><!-- End panel title -->
              <div id="collapse-1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec egestas non urna in fringilla. Praesent consequat est at feugiat faucibus
                </div>
              </div><!-- End Panel collapse -->
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <div class="panel-title">
                <a href="#collapse-2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                  Question Two?
                </a>
              </div><!-- End panel title -->
              <div id="collapse-2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec egestas non urna in fringilla. Praesent consequat est at feugiat faucibus
                </div>
              </div><!-- End Panel collapse -->
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <div class="panel-title">
                <a href="#collapse-3" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                  Question Three?
                </a>
              </div><!-- End panel title -->
              <div id="collapse-3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec egestas non urna in fringilla. Praesent consequat est at feugiat faucibus
                </div>
              </div><!-- End Panel collapse -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End panel group -->

      </section>
    </div><!-- End container -->


<!-- Contact -->

  <div class="container">
    <section>
      <div class="page-header" id="contact">
          <h2>Contact Us.<small> Contact us for more.</small></h2>
        </div><!-- End Page Header -->

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <p>Send us a message, or contact us from the address below</p>


            <address>
              <strong>Wiredwiki Pvt Ltd.</strong></br>
              111, Malviya nagar </br>
              Plot no. 45</br>
              New delhi - 110017</br>
              P: +91 9999999999
            </address>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-8">
            <form action="" class="form-horizontal">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="user-name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-name" placeholder="Enter you name">
                </div>
              </div><!-- End form group -->

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="user-email" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-email" placeholder="Enter you Email Address">
                </div>
              </div><!-- End form group -->

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="user-url" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Your Website</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-email" placeholder="If you have Any.">
                </div>
              </div><!-- End form group -->

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="user-message" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Any Message</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                  <textarea name="user-message" id="user-message" class="form-control" 
                  cols="20" rows="10" placeholder="Enter your Message"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div><!-- End form group -->

              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </div>



            </form>
          </div>
        </div><!-- End the row -->

    </section>
  </div>

  <!-- Feedback-->
    <div class="container">
        <section>
            <div class="page-header" id="feedback">
                <h2>Feedback.<small> Check out the Awesome Feedback</small></h2>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <blockquote>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi gravida quam ac ante rutrum, in mollis ligula mattis. Integer nulla nisi, ullamcorper et posuere vel</p>
                        <footer>John doe</footer>
                    </blockquote>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <blockquote>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi gravida quam ac ante rutrum, in mollis ligula mattis. Integer nulla nisi, ullamcorper et posuere vel</p>
                        <footer>John doe</footer>
                    </blockquote>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <blockquote>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi gravida quam ac ante rutrum, in mollis ligula mattis. Integer nulla nisi, ullamcorper et posuere vel</p>
                        <footer>John doe</footer>
                    </blockquote>
                </div>
            </div><!-- End row -->
        </section>
    </div><!--End Container-->


    <section>
        <div class="well">
            <div class="container text-center">
                <h3>Subscribe for more free stuff</h3>
                <p>Enter your name and email</p>

                <form action="" class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="subscription">Subscribe</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subscription" placeholder="Your name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email address</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Subscribe</button>
                    <hr>
                </form>


            </div><!-- end Container-->

        </div><!-- end well-->
    </section><!-- Call to action -->
<!-- Footer -->

    <footer>
      <hr>
        <div class="container text-center">
        <h3>Subscribe for more free stuff</h3>
        <p>Enter your name and email</p>

        <form action="" class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="subscription">Subscribe</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subscription" placeholder="Your name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Subscribe</button>

        </form>

        <hr>
        <ul class="list-inline">
          <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/wiredwiki">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
        </ul>

        <p>&copy; Copyright @ 2015</p>

      </div><!-- end Container-->


    </footer>


    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->


</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Without some code, no one will be able to help you.

Comment: Can you post your work into jsfiddle please? The more you can give people to work with, the better they can help you out. Thanks.

Comment: @RobR Thanks for your suggestion. I have added my work so far.

Comment: @JakeTaylor I have added code. Please look into it.

Comment: I don't see a link for your custom css stylesheet anywhere.  Do you have a stylesheet of your own? Also.. There's a lot of code going on here.  Why don't you delete everything except for the code that's in question.

Comment: @JakeTaylor I am pretty new to bootstrap. I believe that I am referencing bootstrap's default stylesheets. Please look at code that pertain to "check-generator" id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you're referencing to bootstrap's default stylesheet, but there are a couple of things you need to learn about first.  In order to manipulate the position or appearance of anything in bootstrap according to your own preferences you must make a custom stylesheet and then make sure that it's referenced to after your bootstrap stylesheets so that bootstrap doesn't negate your styles.  You then must know enough css in order to change your styles according to your preferences.  You're currently using javascript to place a background image in a div which is not semantically correct.  Here's a link explaining basics, but you'll really need to learn more about css in order to accomplish what you want with bootstrap. http://bootstrapbay.com/blog/customize-bootstrap/

Comment: No worries.  Once you get a stylesheet set up and start fiddling with your styles it'll be easier to help you further with anything you need to customize.